# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText') in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I'm not sure what the problem is, I'm following a YT tutorial and even the exact same code.

this shows in problem

script.js:37

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')     at showQuestion (script.js:37:31)     at setnextQuestion (script.js:33) at HTMLButtonElement.startGame (script.js:26:5) showQuestion @ script.js:37 setnextQuestion @ script.js:33 startGame @ script.js:26

This is my script code:

```
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton  = document.getElementById('next-btn')

const questionContainElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement        = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement   = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')

let shuffledQuestionIndex;
let quizScore = 0;


startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)

nextButton.addEventListener('click ',() =>{
     currectQuestionIndex++
     setnextQuestion()
})


function startGame(){
    startButton.classList.add('hide')
    shuffledQuestionIndex=question.sort(() =>Math.random() -0.5)
    currectQuestionIndex=0;
    questionContainElement.classList.remove('hide')
    setnextQuestion()
    quizScore=0
}

function setnextQuestion(){
    resetState();
    showQuestion(shuffledQuestionIndex[currectQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question) { 
    questionElement.innerText = question.question; 
    question.answers.forEach((answer) =>{
    const button =document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText=answer.text; 
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if(answer.correct) 
    {
      button.dataset.correctanswer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    })
 }
```

Thankful for any kind of help

Comment: Can you share the HTML code also?

Comment: ```shuffledQuestionIndex=question.sort(() =>Math.random() -0.5)```. Also, you didn't show how you define ```question``` array here.